# How to send data to a servlet using a hyperlink

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to send data to a servlet using a hyperlink. But I'm getting this error "HTTP Status 404 - /SujaneeRestaurant/orderId=13/CancelCater" when I click this cancel button. How can I fix it?

```
<a href="orderId=<%=resultSet.getString("orderId")%>/CancelCater" 
class="btn search_toggle"> Cancel </a>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>CancelCater</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>CancelCater</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CancelCater</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/CancelCater</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```